# How to get sdkman to default to latest point release of a java major version

Tags: java, sdkman

I am using sdkman on my machine to manage Java. when I run `sdk list java` I see all the patch point releases. For example I see Corretto version 21 with id `21-amzn` and Corretto version 21.0.1 with id `21.0.1-amzn` I would like to be able to say something like "sdkman please use the latest Java 21 from Amazon Corretto" with the expectation that sdkman can keep updating to the latest patch release.

When I run `sdk upgrade java` it prints out `java is up-to-date` but when I run `sdk list java` I see the output below clearly there is a newer patch release of corretto 21.0.1 but upgrade seems to treat 21 and 21.0.1 as totally different versions.

**Question:** Is there some way to configure sdkman commands to always use the latest stable release of a major version of java from a specific distro?

```
================================================================================
Available Java Versions for macOS ARM 64bit
================================================================================
 Vendor        | Use | Version      | Dist    | Status     | Identifier
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Corretto      |     | 21           | amzn    | installed  | 21-amzn             
               |     | 21.0.1       | amzn    |            | 21.0.1-amzn         
               |     | 20.0.2       | amzn    |            | 20.0.2-amzn         
               |     | 20.0.1       | amzn    |            | 20.0.1-amzn         
               |     | 17.0.9       | amzn    |            | 17.0.9-amzn         
               |     | 17.0.8       | amzn    |            | 17.0.8-amzn         
               |     | 17.0.7       | amzn    |            | 17.0.7-amzn         
               |     | 11.0.21      | amzn    |            | 11.0.21-amzn        
               |     | 11.0.20      | amzn    |            | 11.0.20-amzn        
               |     | 11.0.19      | amzn    |            | 11.0.19-amzn        
               |     | 8.0.392      | amzn    |            | 8.0.392-amzn        
               |     | 8.0.382      | amzn    |            | 8.0.382-amzn        
               |     | 8.0.372      | amzn    |            | 8.0.372-amzn
```

Comment: Not AFAIK but should be straightforward with a bash script ... Check the current existing versions, parse the output to identify the latest, install it (if you haven't yet) and use it.

Answer (score 2):

**Preface:**

Just from their official docs:
https://sdkman.io/usage#upgrade

**Installing the latest stable version of XXX:**

Install the latest stable version of your SDK of choice (say, Java JDK) by running the following command:

$ sdk install java

**Workaround:**

Create a bash script which

1. Gets the latest version as text
2. Creates the appropriate SDK command
3. Executes the command

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below command to install a specific distribution from a vendor:

```
sdk install java <<Identifier>>
```

where, `Identifier = Version-Dist`

**For example:** If you want to install and use the `21.0.1-amzn` of JDK, then execute this command:

```
sdk install java 21.0.1-amzn
```

where,

- **Version=21.0.1**
- **Dist=amzn**
- **Identifier=Version-Dist=21.0.1-amzn**

When you run the command `sdkman list java`, it shows all the stable JDK distributions that were released from all the vendors in the order of **latest** to **oldest** that you can select.

**Note:** You are correct. After downloading **21.0.1-amzn** and **21-amzn**, I found out that both the distributions point to same implementor version of **Corretto-21.0.1.12.1** after reading the README files from both distributions.

[image]

I guess the **21-amzn** just a **marker** for **21.0.1-amzn** to say that it's a "**final**" distribution unless a newer distribution is available from **Corretto JDK 21.**.

So, if you are install any of them, you are actually installing **Corretto-21.0.1.12.1** on the system.

See the **SDKMAN** JDK Distributions docs [**here**](https://sdkman.io/jdks) for reference.